# NVME SSD disappears from BIOS during Windows operation, but never on BIOS load

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

I have an SSD (**ADATA SX6000LNP**) which contains a full-disk C: partition for Windows 10 and is installed in an NVME slot on the motherboard (**ASRock X370 Pro4** with P6.30 UEFI). I also have an old HDD as a full-disk E: partition, and no other disk drives. Volume usage on the SSD has never went above 20% so far (at 19,96% now) and I haven't experienced any other disk faults.

Sometimes this happens within 5 minutes of booting up, sometimes it happens hours after, Windows "freezes": while the already running applications keep running as normal (until they need to save to C:...), **I can't launch any new applications** - including File Explorer and Task Manager - nor load any websites in already running browsers. This has been happening **for about 18 months** so far, and it happens **2-4 times a month** and doesn't seem to be getting neither more nor less frequent.

When I restart and open **BIOS**, my SSD is **no longer on the list of boot priority**. After manually cutting down power for 10 seconds, **the SSD always shows up** again on the list, but I need to manually set it as #1 on the boot list, because its absence causes the HDD to move up.

The odd thing here is that the SSD **has never disappeared** from the BIOS **without the freeze occuring in Windows** first. Which is unlike many of my Google search results, where other people's NVME disks disappear on BIOS load.

With all of that, I'm at a loss whether the issue with the SSD, the motherboard, Windows 10, unrelated software (Comodo Free Antivirus?), or a combination of the former.

What can I do to fix this issue?

---

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1497235/windows-10-hangs-and-sata-ssd-temporarily-disappears-from-bios) had hardware-Windows interaction, but crashes there seem consistent and much more severe. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1018137/ssd-appears-in-windows-but-not-in-bios) had a wholly different issue, since my SSD is visible in BIOS when it works.

Comment: Blind try (as the possibilities are vast) : Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: See if Event Viewer has any info recorded about freeze, just in case, next time it happens. If there's a Firmware (BIOS/UEFI)Update available for the board, update to latest version.

Comment: @patkim Nothing in Application or System. The latter has a single Error log about the 14:38 shutdown being improper, but has a big gap 12:30-16:30.

Comment: @harrymc `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` ran without errors, while `sfc /scannow` found and repaired "several files"; I can see that some of them had the issue of *"is owned twice or has its security set twice"*. I suppose we should see in a month whether this helped or not.

Comment: Do also a `chkdsk`.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the tip, but `chkdsk` returned *"Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required."* after the two other commands.

Answer (score 1):

SFC is not a good repair program. The fact that it found things to fix
means that some Windows programs were not right for your Windows version.

To be sure that all Windows programs are of the same level requires to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

This operation is the same as a major Windows update, so take the same
precautions. It will conserve your apps and almost all settings.

Comment: Ahh, the *"carpet bombing"* solution - not as bad as the nuclear solution, but still moderately risky and moderately time-consuming. I suppose I'll have to do it eventually, but the bandaid solution works for now.

Answer (score 0):

The following two commands below seemed to fix the issue for **several months**, before it started appearing intermittently a month or so ago, and returned with force yesterday. So you *might** need to run these periodically.

Open Command Prompt as an admistrator, run:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

which should return a message that ends with:

> The operation completed successfully.

and then run:

```
sfc /scannow
```

which should return a message containing:

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
> For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
> windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
> repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

If there were any problems fixed by the latter, opening C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log *might* contain explanation of the fixed problems, like:

> 00000080 Warning: Overlap: Directory ??\C:\Windows\System32\drivers\en-US\ is owned twice or has its security set twice
> Original owner: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Default-Security.Resources, version 10.0.19041.1, arch amd64, culture [l:5]'en-US', nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
> New owner: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Default-Security.Resources, version 10.0.19041.1, arch amd64, culture [l:5]'en-US', nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

If my experience is anything to go by, running these **every 2-3 months** or so should prevent any of these specific crashes from happening.